# Not able to increase TPS in Postgres BDR set up using pgbench utility

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I am getting constant TPS as 500 while using pgbench with different TPS as input .How to increase the TPS in Postgres BDR set up, please suggest .

```
   bdr_version used :  1.0.3-2017-11-21-15283ba
```

**Sample Output and pgbench command input**

## Scenario 1:

> Shared_Buffer = 1024 MB and throttling TPS  as 2000

command used:

```
pgbench -h <hostname> -p 5432 -U postgres -d <dbname> -c 50 -j 50  -r -R 2000
```

O/P :

```
transaction type: TPC-B (sort of)
scaling factor: 1
query mode: simple
number of clients: 50
number of threads: 50
duration: 2400 s
number of transactions actually processed: 1200964
latency average: 894071.370 ms
latency stddev: -nan ms
rate limit schedule lag: avg 893971.489 (max 1819008.190) ms
tps = 500.382936 (including connections establishing)
tps = 500.385107 (excluding connections establishing)
statement latencies in milliseconds:
        0.109225        \set nbranches 1 * :scale
        0.100045        \set ntellers 10 * :scale
        0.085917        \set naccounts 100000 * :scale
        0.064758        \setrandom aid 1 :naccounts
        0.057230        \setrandom bid 1 :nbranches
        0.052089        \setrandom tid 1 :ntellers
        0.049827        \setrandom delta -5000 5000
        0.471368        BEGIN;
        0.678317        UPDATE pgbench_accounts SET abalance = abalance + :delta WHERE aid = :aid;
        0.599331        SELECT abalance FROM pgbench_accounts WHERE aid = :aid;
        80.328257       UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + :delta WHERE tid = :tid;
        15.537372       UPDATE pgbench_branches SET bbalance = bbalance + :delta WHERE bid = :bid;
        0.698180        INSERT INTO pgbench_history (tid, bid, aid, delta, mtime) VALUES (:tid, :bid, :aid, :delta, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
        0.995450        END;
Thu Aug 16 09:52:30 UTC 2018
```

## Scenario 2:

> Shared_Buffer = 1024 MB and throttling TPS  as 6000

Command Used:

```
pgbench -h <hostname> -p 5432 -U postgres -d <dbname> -c 50 -j 50  -r -R 6000
```

O/P:

```
transaction type: TPC-B (sort of)
scaling factor: 1
query mode: simple
number of clients: 50
number of threads: 50
duration: 2400 s
number of transactions actually processed: 1184746
latency average: 1096729.554 ms
latency stddev: -nan ms
rate limit schedule lag: avg 1096628.305 (max 2208483.098) ms
tps = 493.625936 (including connections establishing)
tps = 493.629106 (excluding connections establishing)
statement latencies in milliseconds:
        0.108491        \set nbranches 1 * :scale
        0.098740        \set ntellers 10 * :scale
        0.084497        \set naccounts 100000 * :scale
        0.064168        \setrandom aid 1 :naccounts
        0.056658        \setrandom bid 1 :nbranches
        0.051678        \setrandom tid 1 :ntellers
        0.049427        \setrandom delta -5000 5000
        0.480755        BEGIN;
        0.696514        UPDATE pgbench_accounts SET abalance = abalance + :delta WHERE aid = :aid;
        0.607114        SELECT abalance FROM pgbench_accounts WHERE aid = :aid;
        81.404448       UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + :delta WHERE tid = :tid;
        15.775295       UPDATE pgbench_branches SET bbalance = bbalance + :delta WHERE bid = :bid;
        0.708403        INSERT INTO pgbench_history (tid, bid, aid, delta, mtime) VALUES (:tid, :bid, :aid, :delta, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
        1.009272        END;
Thu Aug 16 11:33:17 UTC 2018
```